# How do I send items to listbox and have an item on each line

Tags: c#

I have this code which sends items from a cell in the database which is in listform to a lsitbox. 
But when it loads in the database it appears in a long list rather than each new item going to a new line..

Can any one help?

```
private void ItemCBx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Listbox1.Items.Clear();
    MAcon.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Process from [Product Family] Where [Product Name] = @ProductName", MAcon);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", ItemCBx.SelectedItem.ToString());
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dtbl);

    if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        Listbox1.Items.Add(dtbl.Rows[0][0]);
    }

    MAcon.Close();
    Listbox1.Show();
    Listbox1.Text.ToString().Split(',').ToList().ForEach(r => Listbox1.Items.Add(r.Trim()));
    //           Define.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ListBox1.Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.text?view=netframework-4.7.1) returns the **selected item**; as you haven't selected any item, it returns an empty string.

Either select the first item before splitting the list...

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
Listbox1.Text.ToString().Split(',').ToList().ForEach(r => Listbox1.Items.Add(r.Trim()));
```

...or split the first element of the `ListBox` directly

```
Listbox1.Items[0].ToString().Split(',').ToList().ForEach(r => Listbox1.Items.Add(r.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write this way as well

```
Listbox1.Items.Clear();
MAcon.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Process from [Product Family] Where [Product Name] = @ProductName", MAcon);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", ItemCBx.SelectedItem.ToString());
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dtbl);
ListBox1.DataSource = dtbl;

ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Process ";
ListBox1.ValueMember = "Process";
MAcon.Close();
Listbox1.Show();    
//           Define.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't put the items into list form

Answer (score 0):

create another listbox,  Send the inital items there then from second listbox send it to inital listbox

```
Listbox1.Items.Clear();
MAcon.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Process from [Product Family] Where [Product Name] = @ProductName", MAcon);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", ItemCBx.SelectedItem.ToString());
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dtbl);
ListBox2.DataSource = dtbl;

ListBox2.DisplayMember = "Process ";
ListBox2.ValueMember = "Process";
MAcon.Close();
Listbox2.Show();    
            listBox2.Text.ToString().Split(',').ToList().ForEach(r => Listbox1.Items.Add(r.Trim()));

//
```